# Custom button with FAB style

Tags: android, flutter, button, dart

I want to make a set of buttons with the ripple effect, elevation and shape like a FAB button. I read that I can only use one FAB button per screen, so I need to create my owns instead of using a set of FAB buttons. [image: The icons design]

How can I achieve the effect? It's possible to modify the FAB code to this?

Comment: What do you mean by FAB button?

Comment: Hi @LonelyWolf, it's a Floating Action Button ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want the fabs in a vertical order wrap them in a **Column** like this

```
class RandomFabScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed: (){},
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10,),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.playlist_play, color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed: (){},
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10,),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white,),
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
            onPressed: (){},
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10,),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.warning, color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed: (){},
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output[image]:

And if you want them in the horizontal order, wrap them in a **Row**

like this

```
class RandomFabScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed: (){},
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10,),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.playlist_play, color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed: (){},
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10,),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white,),
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
            onPressed: (){},
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10,),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.warning, color: Colors.white,),
            onPressed: (){},
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks man! In the documentation says: 

_Use at most a single floating action button per screen. Floating action buttons should be used for positive actions such as "create", "share", or "navigate". (If more than one floating action button is used within a Route, then make sure that each button has a unique heroTag, otherwise an exception will be thrown.)_

It will work with your solution or I need some workaround?

Comment: @Joan Subirats Llaveria that is for Scafold but even there you can use more then one

Comment: I'm receiving this error: ════════ (2) Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.

Comment: Try wrapping each **FloatingActionButton** in the **Hero** widget and specify uniques tags

Comment: For example **Hero( tag : “fab1”, child: FloatingActionButton( ... ))**

Comment: Use different tag values for each Hero...maybe “fab1”, “fab2”, “fab3”, “fab4”

Comment: Finally I assigned a heroTag: null property for every FAB and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Row` to wrap `FloatingActionButton`

code snippet

```
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("click 1");
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.navigation),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("click 2");
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.event),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("click 3");
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.gradient),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("click 4");
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.album),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ]),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("click 1");
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.navigation),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("click 2");
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.event),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("click 3");
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.gradient),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("click 4");
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.album),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ]),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! In the documentation says: Use at most a single floating action button per screen. Floating action buttons should be used for positive actions such as "create", "share", or "navigate". (If more than one floating action button is used within a Route, then make sure that each button has a unique heroTag, otherwise an exception will be thrown.) It will work with your solution or I need some workaround? –